# SSDT for visual studio 2013 installs SQL Server 2014 version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

we have SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

I needed to install BIDS (or SSDT) for developing reports.

I downloaded and installed Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

However during the installation I noticed that it runs SQL Server 2014 setup.

Why doesnt it ask for wich SQL Server version I need SSDT to be installed?

Will it work with SQL Server 2012?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2015 + SSDT, you will have a full backwards compatible version of the BI toolset (2012 and up for SSIS, 2008 and up for other SSAS/SSRS and the relational DB tools). For previous versions of the BI suite, these were tied to specific SQL Server versions:

- SSDT-BI for VS2013 -> SQL Server 2014 support
- SSDT-BI for VS2012 -> SQL Server 2012 support
- BIDS -> SQL Server 2008 support

The current recommendation is to use Visual Studio 2015 + SSDT as it receives regular updates & bug fixes, and is backwards compatible with no need to map to a specific SQL Server version. You can download [SSDT here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).